# .tmx files weird colors in Pygame (python) - Tiled

Tags: python, pygame

*[ See question on Tiled's website : https://discourse.mapeditor.org/t/weird-unexpected-colors-transparent/5173?u=william_bourgeois ]*

I never played with Tiled before today. I spent the whole day doing a pretty big map, and everything is wrong when I load it into my pygame RPG. The first image is how I see it in Tiled, the second image is what actually shows up when I load it.

When I say "everything is wrong", I mean some layers are not appearing and transparency is turned into solid colors (sometimes white, black, pink or yellow).

[How I see my map in Tiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpVRJ.jpg)

[How I see my map in my pygame window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBfdV.png)

I have already tried changing the “trans” argument in the text editor of the .tmx file to “000000”, “ffffff00” and “ff00ff” none of which work, but they have slight variations (some have the glitched parts with pink and yellow, others just white/black).

I tried with other tile sets to make sure it's not a problem with these specific assets. I get the same problem.

[In Tiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D05r.png)

[In my game (pygame)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQbIc.png)

Can someone please explain what is going on and how I can fix my map or at least avoid this mistake in future maps?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to completely delete the **trans** argument in the .tmx file in a text editor. Setting a transparency color causes issues when your assets are already transparent. Good to know! Now everything is working perfeclty!